# javascript chain function continue execution after geolocation request completes

Tags: javascript, geolocation, chaining

I have a code that looks like this:

```
function program(){
  this.bye = function(){
     //some code
     return this;
  }

  this.hello = function(){
     if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess,geoError);
     }
     return this;
  }

  if(this instanceof program()){
     return this.program;
  } else {
     return new program();
  }

}

var PR = new program();
```

My question is this:
How can I accomplish a chain execution such as:

```
TB.hello().bye();
```

and execute bye() when the geolocation response arrives.

I would like to keep the chain execution
without having to execute .bye() from inside geoSuccess function.
Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Using a [promise](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A)? (Which, obviously, won't just magically happen, you'd have to do additional coding though there are some lightweight promise libraries that can help you.)

Comment: You have to work with the callback `geoSuccess` as this is asynchronous.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of geoSuccess being asynchronous. but I have no idea on how to keep the chaining. Any references or examples that could help ?

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas: Promises is the way to go then!

Comment: I think you want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14377406/1587864